# Replacing empty items in a mapped dictionary with 0's

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, replace, null

I am trying to clean up some mapped dictionaries/objects that seem to have empty or null values. Here's an example:

```
 miles_map['California'].t5_data = {'valid_detailed': 0.0,
     'valid_approx': 0.0,
     'valid_unmapped': '',
     'valid_total': 0.0,
     'all_detailed': 0.0,
     'all_approx': 0.0,
     'all_unmapped': '',
     'all_total': 0.0}
```

The empty values could be for any state and occur in any 'column' (ex: vlaid_approx, all_detailed, etc...) so what I want to do is make a function that replaces any of these empty values with 0's. I already have a simple list of all state name I can use for iteration (lets say its called `state_list`). I've tried doing something like this:

```
print(miles_map['California'].t5_data['valid_unmapped'].fillna(0))
```

but it throws an error `'str' object has no attribute 'fillna'`. Also, note that the 'empty' values could be '', '-', null, of NaN. I just want any of those values replaced permanently in the dictionary with 0s. Not sure what I need to do here; any suggestions?

Comment: Can you write something that just *finds* the "empty" values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually. Compile a `set` values you want to replace and modify (or replace) the dictionary

```
data = {'valid_detailed': 0.0, 'valid_approx': 0.0, 'valid_unmapped': '',
        'valid_total': 0.0, 'all_detailed': 0.0, 'all_approx': 0.0,
        'all_unmapped': '', 'all_total': 0.0}

null_vals = {"", "-", None, float("nan")}
default = 0.0

for k, v in data.items():
    if v in null_vals:
        data[k] = default

# or
# data = {k: default if v in null_vals else v for k, v in data.items()}
```